# What are important test scenarios specific to Universal Windows Platform (UWP) application?

Tags: manual-testing, windows-10

We have developed a Windows application using Winforms. Now we are trying to convert it to Universal Windows Platform (UWP) using desktop to appx bridge.

I have to test this app and I'm new to UWP. I know I have to test all the app functions and make sure they work the same way as the original application, but I need to know what to look for that is specific to UWP.

**Are there any test scenarios that only happen with UWP, and if there are, how do I test for them?**

Comment: I have edited your question to make it less broad and more answerable. Feel free to revert my changes if you don't like them.

Answer (score 0):

I do not believe there specific UWP tests that you need to target in order to get the app you have developed in a good spot for release.

If you are indeed not sure/confident after you have applied your testing phase/s over it, you can also do a limited beta release of it, and target specific groups to get more feedback on it. More on that [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/publish/beta-testing-and-targeted-distribution)

Answer (score 0):

I would consider the following testing scenarios with Universal Windows Platform

- Different devices.  The platform is intended is handle this but you might want to have specific devices and characteristics that you test on or for.
- API's  UWP supports REST APIs so you can perform API testing using the platform
- Deployment.  UWP supports deploying to a number of different devices so you may wish to verify that the deployments are functioning successfully.
- Debugging deployed apps to make sure you know how to troubleshoot issues when they arise.

In all cases the specific details of exactly what to test depend on your application specifics.

Answer (score 0):

Universal Windows Platform apps are grouped into the device families that helps you to build a single app that runs on every windows 10 device.
UWP apps use WinRT APIs to provide powerful UI and advanced asynchronous features that are ideal for internet-connected devices.

The following testing scenarios with Universal Windows Platform are:-

1. **Deployment and launch tests**:- Monitors the app during certification testing to record when it crashes or hangs.
2. **Platform Version Launch test**:- Verifies that the Windows app can run on a future version of the OS.
3. **Background tasks cancellation handler validation testing**:- Verifies that the app has a cancellation handler for declared background tasks.
4. **App manifest compliance test**:- Verifies that the contents of app manifest to make sure its contents are correct.
5. **BinScope Binary Analyzer test**:- It examines the app's binary files to check for coding and building practices that make the app less vulnerable to attack or to being used as an attack vector.
6. **Private Code Signing**:- Tests for the existence of private code signing binaries within the app package.
7. **Supported API test**:- Tests the app for the use of any non-compliant APIs.
8. **Performance test**:- The app must respond quickly to user interaction and system commands in order to present a fast and fluid user experience.
9. **App manifest resources test**:- Inspects the resources defined in the app manifest to make sure they are present and valid.
10. **Debug configuration test**:- Tests the app to make sure it is not a debug build or Test the app to make sure it is not a debug build and is not linked to any debug frameworks.
11. **Direct3D feature level test**:- Tests Microsoft Direct3D apps to ensure that they won't crash on devices with older graphics hardware.
12. **App Capabilities test**:- Validates if the app is declaring EnterpriseAuthentication, SharedUserCertificates and DocumentsLibrary capabilities. If any of these capabilities are declared, the test will display a warning to the user.
13. **Supported Directory Structure test**:- Validates that applications are not creating subdirectories as part of installation.
14. **WinJS Background Task test**:- WinJS background task test ensures that JavaScript apps have the proper close statements so apps don’t consume battery.

Top software testing companies also ensure that all the app images adhere to the proper size restrictions, proper file format type restrictions, file encoding and windows security features.